# DataGridView: BackgroundColor и BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms

Почему для задания цвета фона в [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) используется собственное свойство [`BackgroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.backgroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) вместо наследуемого от `Control` [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это наследство от WinAPI. Правда в WinForms это выглядит  немного нелогично. Попробую пояснить. Форма, которая тоже наследуется от `Control`, может быть MDI-контейнером, и у нее появляется два цвета фона: цвет самой формы, в случае MDI - это цвет рамки, и цвет фона MDI-контейнера. И тут все логично, у нас есть `BackColor` - задний или нижний цвет, потому как поверх него могут рисоваться рамки и текст, и `BackgroundColor` - настоящий фон, ниже которого уже ничего не может быть. В случае с `DataGridView` используется именно этот, настоящий фон, так как `BackColor` используется в качестве фона видимых ячеек грида, во всяком случае это больше всего похоже на правду,а код WinAPI закрыт. А отсутствует логика вот где - у MDI-формы, в отличие от `DataGridView`, `BackgroundColor` можно настроить только через интерфейс ОС, нет нужного метода или свойства для этого. Но даже в интерфейсе ОС, при выборе соответствующего пункта, в демонстрационном окне `BackgroundColor` нигде не отображается.

Если мы используем цветовую схему контролов предложенную по умолчанию, то цвет `BackColor` можно задать тут, пункт "**Рельефные объекты**" -

[image: Рельефные объекты]

А `BackgroundColor` - тут, пункт "**Рабочая область приложения**" -

[image: Рабочая область приложения]

То есть они просто по смыслу разные.

Comment: По картинкам, если честно, совершенно не понятно для какой области задается цвет.

Comment: @alexolut дополнил